# How do i derivate this ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a medical doctor, and studying pharmacokinetics.
When a certain drug is given to patients, the patient's body can be divided into two compartments. (central compartment and peripheral compartment)
Drug may moves from central to peripheral, and vice versa. And if the concentration between two compartments establish equilibrium, the drug would be eliminated via urine or bile juice.

[image: diagram]

It can be expressed by using the ODE below
$$
   \frac{dX_C}{dt} = K_{21}X_p - K_{12}X_C - K_{10} X_C
$$
where $X_c$ is the amount of drug in central compartment, $X_p$ the amount of drug in the peripheral compartment, $K_{12}$ and $K_{21}$ are the inter-compartmental transfer rate constants, and $K_{10}$ is the drug elimination constant.

By using Laplace transformation and matrix algebra, the textbook says, its solution would be as below

$$
   \frac{X_0(\alpha-K_{21})}{\alpha - \beta}e^{-\alpha t}
  +\frac{X_0(K_{12}-\beta)}{\alpha - \beta}e^{-\beta t} 
$$
Would you please solve this ODE for me, it is very important for me to write a paper.
Thank you very much

Comment: I think you have given the solution, not the differential equation; where are the derivatives?

Comment: Welcome! Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I changed the title of question. Sorry I'm not good at english and mathematics.. :-(

Comment: To write a paper, I need the derivation of that ODE and solution

Comment: When the textbook says it used matrix algebra, that means a system of ODEs had to be solved. You are missing an ODE describing the time evolution of the peripheral part i.e. what is $\frac{dX_p}{dt}$ ?

Comment: I assume from the picture that $\frac{dX_p}{dt} = K_{12} X_C - K_{21} K_p$.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right. and fortunately, i found the article which derivated that ODE. you don't need to derivate that ODE anymore. thank you for your kindness.

Comment: "Would you please solve this ODE for me, it is very important for me to write a paper." Wow. Don't forget to explain at the start that the paper is not your work...

Comment: May I ask which textbook you mentioned above?